# How does one detect the progress of an embedded Google Drive video?

Tags: video, iframe, google-drive-api

So far, I know that a Google drive video can be embedded in an iframe using the technique below:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<File ID>/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

But once the file is embedded, is there a way to detect the progress of the video, or when the video finishes?

Youtube videos can be manipulated like this using the Youtube player API; is a similar option available for Google Drive videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no similar option for the Google Drive API. If the YouTube Player API already has what you're looking for, why not proceed with using it instead?

With that, I think Google tends to separate the roles of their services. Drive focusing on storage and YouTube for video streaming and anything related to it.

Comment: Hi, it seems like when you play a video from google drive, it gives a URL like this; https://youtube.googleapis.com/embed/?status=ok&hl=en&allow_embed=0&ps=docs&partnerid=30&autoplay=0&docid=1aUJWCNwftLtuXZ2QRMVMIh6cNAlv8VjF however I'm getting an Invalid Paramters error whenviewing it, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @bluejayke. Sorry. I didn't encounter this error before. It's been a while since I've used the Driver API, so I think I won't be much of help right now.